# Appending strings from json object on a condition together efficiently?

Tags: python, json, string, python-3.x

So I have an array of json objects that look like:

```
data = [{key1: 123, key2:"this is the first string to concatenate"},
 {key1: 131, key2:"this is the second string to concatenate"},
 {key1: 152, key2:"this is the third string to concatenate"} ]
```

basically, I am using a for loop right now as follows:

```
all_key2 = ""
data = json.load(json_file)
for p in data: 
    #make it all one big string 
    if langid.classify(p["key2"])=="english": 
        all_key2 = p["key2"] + " " + all_key2
```

so answer should be:

```
"this is the first string to concatenate this is the second string to concatenate this is the third string to concatenate"
```

But this is taking a lot of time because I have a bajillion objects and long strings. Is there a faster way to accomplish this concatentation?

**[EDIT]** Was looking into [lambda](http://caisbalderas.com/blog/iterating-with-python-lambdas/) functions, might  that be the way to go?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
all_key2 = " ".join([elem["key2"] for elem in data if langid.classify(elem["key2"])=="english"])
```

Comment: upvote for using list- instead of gencomp with join.

Comment: Should it be reversed(data)? The OP is prepending

Comment: @Luchko Thank you! Concat order does not matter to me, I will look into join :)

Comment: @Luchko is it possible to use `.join()` with preprocessing on every `key2`?  For example, I call `langid.classify(p["key2"])` to see if the string is in english. In order to classify each string separately, I used a for loop. But whatever passed into join needs to be an already preprocessed sequence, correct? Meaning that I would still have to use a for loop? I've edited my question to match

Comment: yeah,  no problem. you can also add ``if`` statement in your **list comprehension**. (See updates) In addition, you can even preprocess each element before adding to the list by using ``func(elem["key"])`` instead of ``elem["key"]`` in the list comprehension

Comment: @ocean800 I just updated code for joining elements with  space symbol (" " .join instead of "".join