# Appending n number of strings from json object together efficiently?

Tags: python, json, string, python-3.x

So I have a json object like this:

```
data = [{key1: 123, key2:"this is the first string to concatenate"},
 {key1: 131, key2:"C'est la deuxième chaîne à concaténer"},
 {key1: 152, key2:"this is the third string to concatenate"},
 {key1: 152, key2:"this is the fourth string to concatenate"} ]
```

where I want to concatenate all the english `key2` strings together like:

```
"this is the first string to concatenate this is the third string to concatenate this is the fourth string to concatenate"
```

and based of of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43574639/appending-strings-from-json-object-on-a-condition-together-efficiently) question I am doing it like so:

```
all_key2 = " ".join([elem["key2"] for elem in data if langid.classify(elem["key2"])=="english"])
```

However, is it possible to have a limit on the number of items get joined into the list? for example, what if I only wanted to concatenate a max of 2 english `key2`'s ? That means that I would want something like this:

```
"this is the first string to concatenate this is the third string to concatenate"
```

Basically, once I concatenate some max number of english sentences, I don't want to concatenate anymore. I could do this with a for loop like so:

```
all_key2 = ""
english_count =0 
data = json.load(json_file)
for p in data: 
    if english_count > 2: 
        break 
    #make it all one big string 
    if langid.classify(p["key2"])=="english": 
        #increment english_count 
        #join here
```

But due to performance issues I want to avoid `for` loops.... is there a way to accomplish this?

**[EDIT]** The reason that I just don't slice the filtered list is because generating the filtered list takes a lot of time. I want to place a max `english_count` condition so that I generate only part of the entire list

Comment: What performance issues? "Premature optimization is the root of all evil" https://xkcd.com/1691/  Vectorized methods can't stop early, `for` loops can (using `break`)

Comment: @cco I have a bazillion objects that each have many long strings. Using for loops is taking way too long, and the `.join()` has significant performance boosts

Comment: List comprehensions can't stop early either; the will always run the entire list.

Comment: @cco So.... I'd have to use a for loop then? Either that or find some other faster way than list comprehensions?

Comment: I love list comprehensions, but not in cases where stopping early is important.  Ordinary `for` loops are a good tool in those cases (generators are another way to stop early, but too complicated for this case, I think).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a `for` loop rather than a list comprehension lets you stop early, like this:

```
filtered_list = []
for elem in data:
    if langid.classify(elem["key2"])=="english":
        filtered_list.append(elem["key2"])
        if len(filtered_list) > 2:   # or whatever your max is
            break
result = " ".join(filtered_list)
```